# Best practices to use LinQ with criteria object

Tags: linq, object, criteria

We just moved from ADO.Net to Entity Framework.
I have a SearchCriteria object which contents many fields. 
Because it has many fields, it has many possibilities for where clause.
What is the best practices to do this with LinQ and EntityFramework.

Comment: I figured it out. We need to use the IQueryable<DataObject> and keep adding the where clause the finally fetch the data.

Austin

Comment: @AustinTX Then you should write that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. We need to use the IQueryable  and keep adding the where clause the finally fetch the data.